# My mother's name is on my car title, how can I protect my ownership of the car in the event of her death?

Tags: car, auto-loan

My mom bought me a car in April 2014. We went to the dealer together and I was going to buy the car.

The dealer's finance dept. told me that they could only get 2 of the 3 credit reporting bureau scores so they could sell me a car so my mom bought it for me.

My name isn't on the auto loan from Golden One Credit Union and my name is not on the registration.

My mom is 86. In the event of her death what can I do to protect myself so I don't lose the car.

The car is insured in my name and I have paid the monthly car loan, the registration and all other expenses associated with the car.

Comment: Get the car signed over to you. Also, how it is set up in her will - that will determine who gets the car after her death if it is in her name at that time.

Comment: Until your name is on the title and registration, it isn't your car -- it's hers.

Answer (score 10):

It's her car.  Unlike what Ross said in the comments she **can't** sign it over to you--she doesn't own it yet.  The best you'll be able to do is have her leave it to you in her will--but beware that you very well might need to refinance the loan at that point.

Comment: Good point; missed the loan part ;)

Comment: Maybe that ship has already sailed, YMMV, but some auto loans have a life insurance you can buy in tandem so the principal is paid off by the insurance in case of a sinister. My home mortgage has such insurance.